# laravel ui auth /login 404 not found

Tags: laravel

i cant access the auth pages it always redirect 404 not found .
it was work just fine before ,i dont know whats going on suddenly

this is my route file

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect(app()->getLocale());
});

Auth::routes();
```

and this my route list

```
+--------+----------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Domain | Method                                 | URI                                                        | Name                         | Action
                                                  | Middleware                                                  |
+--------+----------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
                                     |                                                            |                              |
                                                  | App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated                 |
|        | POST                                   | login                                                      | generated::csqSXSmjhYevTLX7  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web                                                         |
|        |                                        |                                                            |                              |
                                                  | App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated                 |
|        | POST                                   | logout                                                     | logout                       | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web                                                         |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | password/confirm                                           | password.confirm             | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@showConfirmForm    | web                                                         |
|        |                                        |                                                            |                              |
                                                  | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate                            |
|        | POST                                   | password/confirm                                           | generated::FOcpGH5OrG9S8e7r  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@confirm            | web                                                         |
|        |                                        |                                                            |                              |
                                                  | App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate                            |
|        | POST                                   | password/email                                             | password.email               | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web                                                         |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | password/reset                                             | password.request             | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web                                                         |
|        | POST                                   | password/reset                                             | password.update              | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web                                                         |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | password/reset/{token}                                     | password.reset               | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web                                                         |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | register                                                   | register                     | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web                                                         |
|        |                                        |                                                            |                              |
                                                  | App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated                 |
|        | POST                                   | register                                                   | generated::28dngmMiIB5ZE1p8  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web                                                         |
|        |                                        |                                                            |                              |
                                                  | 
|        | GET|HEAD                               | {locale}                                                   | site.index                   | App\Http\Controllers\Site\HomeController@index                         | web                                                         |
|        |                                        |                                                            |                              |
                                                  | App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale                               |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | {locale}/chooseus/{chooseus}                               | site.chooseus.detail         | App\Http\Controllers\Site\ChooseusController@detail                    | web                                                         |
|        |                                        |                                                            |                              |
                                                  | App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale                               |
|        | POST                                   | {locale}/contact-us/send                                   | site.contact.send            | App\Http\Controllers\Site\ContactController@send                       | web                                                         |
|        |                                        |                                                            |                              |

+--------+----------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

i tried to reinstall laravel ui but that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Your route `{locale}` may que interfering with the `login` route.  Since both are first level routes, the `{locale}` is taking precedence, therefore not showing you the `login`` route.

You should consider using other route syntax, like `/content/{locale}` for example.